# Relative path does not work when jar run through command line but works when run through Netbean

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have added "Images" folder inside "src" folder in Java project.

For setting top left image on title bar I am using image from Image folder.
To do that I have written code
        `Image img=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("src/Images/Sell Smart2 copy.jpg");
        frame.setIconImage(img);`

This works fine when project run through Netbeans
But when I run jar of that project through command line using command "java -jar project.jar" then Image is not shown.

Why this problem coming ? Any solution for that

Thanks,
Image added for refernce.

[image]

Comment: i'd use absolute paths, ie "/src/Images/Sell Smart2 copy.jpg"

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy :: Thats what I used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drop the src from your path.
Also, while loading jarred images, you should be using getClass().getResource()

Comment: Hi @maneesh , I droped src folder name and tried with ""/Images/Sell Smart2 copy.jpg" but it didn't work.  Now trying to use getClass().getResource() as you suggested. will get back to results

Answer (score 1):

1. have you checking src folder is included in jar when you create a jar?
   use jar -xf or similar option to see jar contents or use winrar to see jar contents.

Comment: : HI , I have open jar using winRar and didn't find 
"src" folder under it. It contains Images folder directly inside jar. Can you me in adding src under jar or any other option.

Answer (score 1):

In jar you can use

`getClass().getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream();`

And when you get the stream, you can do anything you wanted.

But remember when using resourseStream while you are running you project in netbeans may be it will not work but when you make jar it'll work.

Comment: Your suggestion is syntactically incorrect. Without `getClassLoader()`, `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` works equally well both in the IDE and out. Even corrected, your answer simply repeats the earlier (+1) suggestion of @maneesh. This answer should probably be deleted.

Comment: HI @Ankit :: I have not tried what you given , but I tried solution given by @maneesh and it worked in IDE and in command line both. Thanks for your reply :)